# Какую бы вы сделали бекенд архитектуру для месенджера?

Tags: java, .net, golang, архитектура, backend

Задача чисто теоретическая, поэтому тонкости можно не уточнять. А если от тонкостей что-то зависит, то можно об этом написать.

Понятно только то что нужно сделать конкурента Viber, Telegram, Whatsapp. Похоже так обычно не делают, а сначала нужно требования конкретные собрать.
Допустим сейчас нужно накидать верхнеуровнево архитектуру в документацию, которая будет основой дальше, когда будут понятны другие требования.

Сразу понимаю что зависит от дальнейших планов, если планируем через год захватить мир и 1B активных пользователей, то сразу микросервисы нужно рассматривать, иначе можно начать с монолита.

Но возможно есть сразу какие-то важные моменты/подходы в таком деле которые будет полезно знать.
К примеру:

- где хранить сообщения?
- Какие сервисы выделить?
- Как обеспечить передачу и консистентность сообщений между разными частями мира в разных датацентрах?
- Как балансировать входную нагрузку если 1М запрос в секунду на 1 инстанс сервера.

Comment: Сначала сделайте план, а потом уже, когда будут конкретные вопросы, приходите и задавайте их. Пока что ничего объективного по вопросу дать невозможно, и он скатится в обсуждения.

Comment: У меня нет такой задачи поэтому и плана не будет. Задал вопрос только ради интереса.

Comment: Возьмите любой опенсорс проект для jabber/xmpp  и посмотрите. Тот же openfire

Comment: @KoVadim Пока не вижу репу сервера, только клиенты. А вообще даже в опенсорсе не всегда описывают архитектуру и рациональ. Посмотреть код - хорошо, но это будут субьективные интерпритации и много лишнего. Помимо кода, одного аспекта архитектыры, есть еще и много напрямую не связанного. К примеру как деплоят, сколько инстансов каких, где, почему именно так деплоят? То есть в коде много решений без указания проблем. Поэтому задал такой вопрос

Comment: Похоже xmpp  - это распределенный протокол https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP, о таком подходе я даже и не думал. Больше в голове были централизованные подходы.

Comment: Скажу больше, многие современные мессенджеры использовали и используют jabber/xmpp внутри.

Comment: Это один из дизайн вопросов, которые можно встретить на собеседовании. Погуглите, возможно вы найдёте разбор именно такой задачи в сети. Но без конкретных требований не ждите конкретных рекомендаций

Comment: @tym32167, вы совершенно правы. Похоже нужно как минимум вытягивать требования у того кто спрашивал. Может и есть какие-то базовые практики, но как вижу действительно без конкретики сложно сказать что-то. А выманивать требования - это тоже мастерство!

Comment: чтобы понять, какие требования спрашивать - надо понять сначала, какие опции у вас есть для реализации. Вот надо вам хранилище - вы знаете, как делают хранилища для чатов? Можно и реляционную БД взять, можно no-sql решение, можно их комбинировать в in-memory кешем. А какие отличия этих решений? Наверное, масштаб, сколько надо юзеров/чатов поддерживать, сколько онлайн, сколько истории хранить, какие запросы для истории поддерживать, как синхронизировать историю на клиентах, какие фичи на клиентах держать, какой тип медиа поддерживать. Поищите в инете внутреннее устройство телеги например.

Comment: Но вот вы выберите No_SQL решение, что вам в первую очередь решать придется? Наверное, вам надо будет разобраться в форматом, что вы будете хранить, надо ли какую то избыточность иметь (отношений то там нет, как в SQL БД), какие поля и как надо индексировать. А надо ли вам горизонтально масштабироваться? А если надо какой индекс для шардинга использовтаь? А какие буквы из CAP вам надо поддерживать? Ну и прочее и прочее. И я только про хранение написал, а что кроме хранения? А что про шифрование? Монтиторинг? Онказоустойчивость? Безопасность? и т.д.

Comment: Забавно, что именно сегодня мне попалась на глаза именно такая задача https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/design-messenger/